# Allowing admins to add users with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to make it so only admins can add uses with devise. I've gotten it mostly working however now when I'm logged in as an admin and submit the sign up form it kicks me back with the error: `You are already signed in.`

I've tried to follow the instructions here: http://wiki.summercode.com/rails_authentication_with_devise_and_cancan but it doesn't seem to mention this situation.

Do I need to do further overriding in the `editors_controller` to allow this?

Here are my routes ("editors" is the name of my user model):

```
devise_for :admins, :skip => [:registrations]

as :admin do
  get 'admin/editors'        => 'editors#index',                  as: :admin_editors
  get 'admin/editors/new'    => 'editors#new',                    as: :new_editor
  delete 'admin/editors/:id' => 'editors#destroy',                as: :destroy_editor
end


devise_for :editors, :skip => [:registrations],  :controllers => { :registrations => "editors" }
```

and my `editors_controller` in "app/controllers/"

```
    class EditorsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :check_permissions, :only => [:new, :create, :cancel]
  skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication

  def dashboard
    render "editors/dashboard.html.haml"
  end

  def index
    @editors = Editor.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end

  private
    def check_permissions
      authorize! :create, resource
    end
end
```

**EDIT**
I noticed this `Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML` in the logs when I submit the form. I had suspected that perhaps the `skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication` wasn't being called, but assumed that because the `EditorsController` was inheriting from `RegistrationController` that before filter would work properly. Is that not the case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to implement your own `create` method on `EditorsController` instead of inheriting that action from `Devise::RegistrationsController`.  As you're seeing, the method in `Devise::RegistrationsController` will first check to see if you're already logged in and kick you back  if you are.  If you're not logged in it will create a `User` account and then log you in as that user.

You're trying to get around that problem with `skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication`, but it's likely that your form is `POST`ing to `/editors` instead of `/admin/editors`.  So, you'll need to add a route that allows you to get to `create` on the `EditorsController` :

```
as :admin do
  post 'admin/editors' => 'editors#create'
  # your other :admin routes here
end
```

Then you'd want to implement a scaled down version of `create`.  You probably want something kind of like this :

```
class EditorsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    if resource.save
      redirect_to admin_editors_path
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

  # your other methods here
end
```

You'll also want to make sure that the `admin/editors/new` template is pointing the form to the correct route (`'admin/editors'`).

Comment: hello Jeremey i've tried your create action but it's still bypassing the form and licking me out with a "You are already signed in" message. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

None of the googleable solutions worked when I tried them.   This works

What I did was create a new action in the controller and a new route for it, and connect the links on my views that normally connect to create to now call my route and action.

But that wasn't enough. Because Devise is listening and will grab any add you try to do and validate it through it's own code. So instead I just add the new user record with a sql insert.

**Add this route**

```
post 'savenew', to: 'users#savenew'
```

**Add this action to the user controller:**

```
def savenew
  rawsql = "insert into users (email, created_at,updated_at) values ('#{user_params[:email]}',now(), now())"
  sql = rawsql
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
  redirect_to action: 'index''
end
```

**View: new.html.erb**
change the form_for so that submit will go to the new route and action, not the default Rails one.

```
<%= form_for User, :url => {:action => "savenew"} do |f| %>
```

Comment: I couldn't get your solution to work for me, but it gave me some ideas that I was able to use.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using Rails 4.2.6 here (my model is User instead of Editor).  The following solution bypasses (I think) any devise actions that may interfere with new User creation by the admin:

**Add this action to the Users controller:**

```
def savenew
  User.create_new_user(user_params)
  redirect_to action: 'index'
end
```

**Add this private method to the Users controller if it does not exist:**

```
private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password,      
                               :password_confirmation)
end
```

**Add this to config/routes.rb:**

```
match '/savenew', to: 'users#savenew', via: :post
```

**Add this class method to the User model:**

```
def self.create_new_user(params)
  @user = User.create!(params)
end
```

I don't have a separate Admin class in my application.  Instead, I defined an admin attribute for Users and check for it with a `:validate_admin` `before_action` filter in the UsersController.

I wanted to be able to create a new user from the `:index` view, so I added a button:

```
<%= button_to 'New User', '/new_user', class: 'btn btn-primary',
                          method: :get %>
```

You might have to tweak the above solution if you have any `after_create` actions in the User model (e.g. sending a welcome email).