# Devise/CanCanCan - Allow Admin To Create New Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

I'm using rails 4.0.2, devise and [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan). I'm trying to allow an admin to create new users. Admin users are assigned with a boolean field in the users table.

In ability.rb I have the following:

```
can :manage, :all if user.admin?
```

Following some of the advise in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19017978/allowing-admins-to-add-users-with-devise) question I created a new controller called AdminsController and it looks like so:

```
class AdminsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
      def create
        build_resource(sign_up_params)
        if resource.save
          redirect_to admin_editors_path
        else
          clean_up_passwords resource
          respond_with resource
        end
      end

      def new
        build_resource({})
      end
end
```

I've tried to configure the routes as well:

```
  devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations]
  as :user do
    get 'user/admin' => 'admins#new'
    post 'user/admin' => 'admins#create'
    get 'users/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => :edit_user_registration
    post 'users/' => 'devise/registrations#create', :as => :user_registration
    get 'users/cancel' => 'devise/registrations#cancel', :as => :cancel_user_registration
  end
```

In devise/registrations/edit.html I'm trying to add a link to allow the user to create a new user like so:

```
<%= link_to "Create User", user_admin_path %>
```

The problem is that that link just redirects me to the home page with the message

> You are already signed in.

I'm not really sure what I'm getting wrong here so any help at all would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `build_resource` method in the Devise::RegistrationsController( on [github](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb) ),

```
def build_resource(hash=nil)
  self.resource = resource_class.new_with_session(hash || {}, session)
end
```

builds a new resource by based the session. The user in the session (in this case) are the admin and are signed in.

You want to create a new User based on a new user instance of the user class, not based on a session.

Something like this should work.

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
 def new_user
  authorize! :manage, User
   @user = Users.new
 end
 def create_user
    @user = User.new(permitted_params.user)
    authorize! :manage, User
    if @user.save
     #success
    else
     #error
    end

 end
end
```

routes.rb

```
get "admins/new_user" => "admins#new_user", as: :admins_new_user
post "admins/create_user/:id" = "admins/create_user", as: :admins_create_user
```

link to new user

```
<%= link_to "Create User", admins_new_user_path %>
```

Form

```
  <%= form_for(@user, :url => admins_create_user_path) do |f| %>
  #fields and submit
  <% end %>
```

permitted_params.user is a method in a PermittedParams class, and it might be handy for you.

By passing current_user into the method you can allow different parameter for different users.

models/permitted_params.rb

```
class PermittedParams < Struct.new(:params, :current_user)
  def user
    params.require(:user).permit(*user_attributes)
  end
  def user_attributes
    if current_user.admin?
      [:name, :email,:password, :password_confirmation, :role ,:admin]
    else
      [ :name, :email, :remember_me,:password, :password_confirmation, ]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I still get redirected to the home page with the message "you are already signed in". Do you think there's an issue with my routes?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I overlooked it. You should solve this outside devise. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Updated. You should solve this outside devise because you just create users you don't sign them in or send out register mails. Devise only messes simple user creation up.

Comment: Thanks this is definitely a huge improvement. I'm getting the new_user form but it's not saving for some reason. My logs look something like this:                                                                 Started POST "/admins/create_user" for 192.168.1.70 at 2014-04-03 14:00:50 +0100
Processing by AdminsController#create_user as HTML
  Parameters: {#all_the_params, "commit"=>"Create User"}
  User Load (4.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction

Comment: Are #all_the_params permitted?

Comment: Yeah, there's no problem there. I tried to debug a bit and other issues showed up. At first I forgot to change AdminsController > Devise::RegistrationsController to AdminsController::ApplicationController but when I did I got the error 'circular dependancy detected" also the permitted_params call in the controller was giving me a no method error so I left that out for now. It's a great touch and I just thought I'd put it in when the new user functionality was working :)

Comment: You kan learn more about strong parameters in this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/371-strong-parameters) and on [it's github page](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/). Don't forget to accept or/and vote if you like the answer. I am trying to get over 2000 to day ;)

Comment: OH sorry! I had a typo. It should be `AdminsController < ApplicationController` not `AdminsController::ApplicationController`. I'll correct it

Comment: I haven't tried it on my machine yet because I've run into some problems but a colleague did and it seems to be working perfectly! Thank you, and I hope you get your goal today :)

Comment: Hi, I have a error message here :
undefined local variable or method `permitted_params' for #<UsersController:0xb6729f14>
Can you tell me what is the problem ?